# mysql compare enum

Tags: sql, mysql

Here is a table i have

```
CREATE TABLE `CUSTOMERSTATUSTYPES` (
  `CustomerStatusId` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `CustomerStatusName` enum('ACTIVE','SUSPEND','TERMINATE','CANCEL') default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`CustomerStatusId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When i write

```
GROUP BY ... WHERE cst.CustomerStatusName<>'TERMINATE' ;
```

i get a syntax error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE
>   cst.CustomerStatusName<>'TERMINATE''
>   at line 1

How do i correctly check this?

Comment: you should be using != which is standard and more portable than <>

Comment: @longneck: I think you'll find that the ANSI SQL standard specifies `<>`, and not `!=`, as the "not equals" operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The WHERE clause must come before the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to put the WHERE clause **before** the GROUP BY clause, or you need to use the HAVING keyword.

See here for more info:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/3469351/The-HAVING-and-GROUP-BY-SQL-clauses.htm